# Multiple ListViews with multiple instances of the same custom adapter in one activity

Tags: android, class, listview, adapter

I have been trying to display run history of a runner based on some categories such as all runs that had a time of 15 seconds will come under a single listview, similarly all runs that had a time of 20 seconds will come under another listview. On the top of each listview there is a framelayout that contains the time heading and the total number of runs under that. So if we had 2 runs under the 15 seconds heading then there would be a framelayout with these two headings and under it there would be a listview containing two run items. 
Since I am fetching the run history from a database, I am creating the framelayouts and listviews dynamically through coding.

The problem which I am facing is that when I create more then one listview (either through code or through xml) inside the same activity and use the same adapter class (but more then one instance of it) for these listviews then all the listviews get populated with the arraylist that was given to the last adapter object. Please consider the following code for some more clarity:

```
for(int i=0; i<listOfLists.size(); i++) {
    linearLayout.addView(frameLayoutList.get(i));
    CustomAdapter2 customAdapter2 = new 
    CustomAdapter2(getBaseContext(), listOfLists.get(i));
    ListView listView = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter2);
    linearLayout.addView(listView);
}
```

I tried creating the exact same new class for the adapter with a different class name (customAdapter3) and populated two listviews with customAdapter2 and customAdapter3 and they were populating the listviews with correct data.
Since I don't know before hand how many listviews will be used I can't create different adapter classes for all of the listviews.
Is it somehow possible to use the same adapter class for all the listviews with different instances of it for each of the listviews?

Here is the code for the adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
Context context;
public static  List<Run> list = null;

public CustomAdapter2(Context context, List<Run> l) {

    this.context = context;
    this.list = l;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void add(Run run) {
    list.add(run);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



public double getScreenSize() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int dens = dm.densityDpi;
    double wi = (double) width / (double) dens;
    double hi = (double) height / (double) dens;
    double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    return screenInches;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(getScreenSize() <= 4)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_small, parent, false);
        else
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.trophyTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trophyTextView);
        holder.normalTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.normalTextView);
        holder.raceDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.raceTime1TextView);
        holder.raceTimeUnit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.raceTime2TextView);
        holder.raceDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        holder.raceTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(position == 0) {
        holder.trophyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.normalTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.trophyTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.normalTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.normalTextView.setText("" + (position + 1));
    }

    holder.raceDuration.setText(list.get(position).getTimeDistance());
    holder.raceTimeUnit.setText(list.get(position).getUnit());
    holder.raceDate.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
    holder.raceTime.setText(list.get(position).getTime());

    return convertView;
}


private class ViewHolder {
    TextView trophyTextView;
    TextView normalTextView;
    TextView raceDuration;
    TextView raceTimeUnit;
    TextView raceDate;
    TextView raceTime;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list in your adapter is static, so it's the same for all the instances of the class.

Replace `public static  List<Run> list = null;` with `public List<Run> list = null;`

I would also advise you to make it private instead of public (and create a getter if you need to access it from outside the class).

Comment: Thanks, I was going nuts. Can't believe I missed out the static part. Thanks again man.